# ADAL: Returned nonce did not match

Tags: ruby, sinatra, omniauth, azure-active-directory, adal

I am receiving the exact error shown here "https://github.com/AzureAD/omniauth-azure-activedirectory/issues/22".

Per the original poster I get the error on the exact same spot"

```
JWT::DecodeError at /auth/azureactivedirectory/callback
Returned nonce did not match.
file: azure_activedirectory.rb location: validate_and_parse_id_token line: 289
```

Please help.  I'm following the exact example here (for sinatra):

https://github.com/AzureAD/omniauth-azure-activedirectory

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'omniauth-azure-activedirectory'

set :port, 8081

configure do
  enable :sessions

  use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :azure_activedirectory, ENV['AAD_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['AAD_TENANT']
end

helpers do
  def current_user
    !session[:uid].nil?
  end
end

before do
  pass if request.path_info =~ /^\/auth\//

  redirect to('/auth/azureactivedirectory') unless current_user
end

get '/auth/azureactivedirectory/callback' do
  session[:uid] = env['omniauth.auth']['uid']
  redirect to('/')
end

get '/auth/failure' do
  'I am crying!'
end

get '/' do
  puts 'Spot 4'
  puts env['omniauth.auth'].to_s
  request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_s
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Very odd behavior I have just uncovered.  I seem to be able to reproduce problem in Safari and Chrome but not in Firefox ... This is very confusing!

Comment: Ok I found a workaround.  The fact that browsers seemed to be the variance I guessed it was tied to cookies.

I changed the code and added the following:

  use Rack::Session::Cookie,
      :key => 'rack.session',
      :path => '/',
      :expire_after => 14400,
      :secret => 'your_secret_goes_here'

This seems to work just fine!   I would like a better answer though.  Why is this occurring?

Comment: I am not familiar with omni-auth, but I am familiar with OIDC. When the Client makes an OpenIdConnect Request it includes a query parameter 'nonce'. 'nonce' is a once-used, non-guessable value that will be returned in the JWT token and needs to be validated against the 'nonce' sent in the request. Many runtimes use cookies to 'remember' the 'nonce'.